# Pass value(words symbol and number) from template to url.py in django

Tags: regex, django

I am new in `django`. I want to pass the log file name from template to view the log file name is `Fuze-2015-04-28-08-07-34_28744226_30892878.log`. When I click on a tag in html it gives me error `page not found`

**ERROR**
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'parselog' with arguments '('Fuze-2015-04-27-00-42-55.log',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['parselog/(?P[-\w]+)/$']

Error during template rendering

In template C:\fuzeLog\fuzeLog\templates\index.html, error at line 61
Reverse for 'parselog' with arguments '('Fuze-2015-04-27-00-42-55.log',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['parselog/(?P[-\w]+)/$']

61:{{ logfile }}

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style='overflow:auto; width:400px; height:500px;'>
{% for logfile in logfiles %}
<a href="{% url 'parselog' logfile %}">{{ logfile }}</a>
<br>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:

    url(r'^$', 'fuzeLogApp.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^parselog/(?P<logfile>[-\w]+)/$', 'fuzeLogApp.views.parselog', name='parselog'),


    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**view.py**

```
def home(request):
    try:
        OSName = platform.system()
        print OSName

        if OSName == "Windows":
            path="C:\\Users\\Ish_waR\\AppData\\Local\\FuzeBox\\Logs"  # insert the path to your directory
            Logfile_list =os.listdir(path) 
        else:
            pass

    except IOError as e:
        print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
        return render_to_response('index.html',{'OSName':"I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return render_to_response('index.html',{'OSName':OSName ,'logfiles': Logfile_list},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def parselog(request,logfile):
   print logfile
```

Comment: It's a keyword argument in the url, not a plain arg. You need to do logfile=logfile in the url template tag.

Comment: <a href="{% url 'parselog' logfile=logfile %}">{{ logfile }}</a>

Like above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url) in index.html, and pass the `logfile` variable as an argument

```
{% for logfile in logfiles %}
<a href="{% url 'parselog' logfile %}">{{ logfile }}</a>
<br>
{% endfor %}
```

In urls.py, you need to allow for '.' in the regex:

```
url(r'^parselog/(?P<logfile>[\w.-]+)/$', 'fuzeLogApp.views.parselog', name='parselog'),
```

See [Common Regular Expressions for Django URLs](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Guides/blob/master/common_url_regex.md#common-regular-expressions-for-django-urls).

Comment: I got below error when i replace my index.html code by ur given code

NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'parselog' with arguments '('.Fuze-PackagedLogsList.dat',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['parselog/(?P<logfile>[-\\w]+)/$']

Comment: Can you post your complete urls.py? It looks like you have a url that begins with `url(r'^parselog/`, which your code is trying to pattern match for some reason.

Comment: Please add the urls as an edit to your question, for easier viewing. Thanks.

Comment: **urls.py**

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'fuzeLogApp.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^parselog/(?P<logfile>[-\w]+)/$', 'fuzeLogApp.views.parselog', name='parselog'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

Comment: It looks like the regex isn't properly catching the argument. Maybe it's because you have an extra slash in `[-\\w]`.

Comment: Can you please help me
**Now it given template rendering error**

Error during template rendering

In template C:\fuzeLog\fuzeLog\templates\index.html, error at line 61
Reverse for 'parselog' with arguments '('Fuze-2015-04-27-00-42-55.log',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['/parselog/(?P<logfile>[-\\w]+)/$']

Comment: Hi please help me  I am not able to solve this problem

Comment: Glad to help! Is there a reason for not upvoting the answer? (you can upvote answers that you accept)

Comment: While I m upvoting answer it  display message tat "require 15 reputation "

Comment: Please help  me to solve below problem        


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028298/not-able-to-find-static-file-path-page-redirect-to-another-page